# Simplifying integral comparison

Tags: integration, inequality, integral-inequality

I'm trying to prove that, given some finite numbers $a$ and $b$ ($a < b$) and a non-negative,continuous,smooth function $f(k,x)$, the following inequality:

$$\int_a^b e^{-f(k_1,x)}\;\mathrm{d}x > \int_a^b e^{-f(k_2,x)}\mathrm{d}x$$

can be simplified to

$$\int_a^b f(k_1,x)\; \mathrm{d}x < \int_a^b f(k_2,x) \; \mathrm{d}x$$

For any some $k_1,k_2 \in \mathbb{R}$. Does this hold? If yes, could you give me a hint on how to prove it.

Comment: Can you please show what you have tried to prove this?

Comment: Hi @sai-kartik! I changed the problem to give some additional info about the function. The functions $f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x)$ are derived from the a non-negative function $f(k,x)$ but with different $k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The claim is false. On the interval $[a,b]=[0,2]$, consider $g(x)=\frac25$ and $h(x) = \lfloor x\rfloor$. Then
$$
\int_0^2 g(x)\,dx = \frac45 < 1 = \int_0^2 h(x)\,dx
$$
and yet
$$
\int_0^2 e^{-g(x)} = 2e^{-2/5} \approx 1.34 < 1.37 \approx 1+e^{-1} = \int_0^2 e^{-h(x)} \,dx.
$$
It just remains to choose a function $f(k,x)$ such that $f(0,x) = g(x)$ and $f(1,x) = h(x)$, say.

Comment: Hi @greg-martin. Thanks for your comment. Do you have a counterexample wherein f(k,x) is continuous and smooth?

Comment: Any function can be approximated by a smooth function to within arbitrary accuracy. Really there's no reason to expect one inequality to imply the other: exponentiating drastically changes the relative sizes of numbers. Try playing around with functions with roughly the same sizes as in my example; I'm sure you'll find one soon enough.

Comment: I see. Are there cases where this will work? For example, if f(k,x) is also convex. @greg-martin